# create instances and store them in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a student class and every student instance created needs to be stored in an array.attributes can be given in program or read from user input.how do I extend my main() method to store it? i am stuck .

Here is my student class code:

```
public class student {

    int   studentID;
    String studentName,gender,course;
 /** set the student name
  * @param studentName
 */
 public  void        setName(String studentName){
this.studentName = studentName;
 }
  /**
  * set student ID number
  * @param studentID 
   */
   public  void        setNewId(int studentID){
   this.studentID = studentID;
  }
   /**
   * Set student gender
   * @param gender 
   */
   public void setGender(String gender){
  this.gender = gender;
 }
 /**
  * set the course
  * @param course 
  */
   public  void        setCourse(String course){
   this.course = course;
 }
 /**
  *Gets the Student's ID Number.
  *@return IdNumber Student ID Number.
  */
  public  int      getIdNumber(){
return studentID;
 }

  /**
  *Gets the Student's Name.
  *@return studentName Student Name.
  */
 public  String      getName(){
return studentName;
 }
 /**
  * Get student gender
  * @return 
   */
 public String getGender(){
  return gender;
 }
 /**
  *Gets the Student's Course.
  *@return course Student Course.
  */

  public  String     getCourse(){
return course;
  }
  /**
  *Prints Student Informations.
  *@return Student ID Number, name, gender and course.
    */

  public void printStudent(){
 System.out.print(studentID+""+studentName+""+gender+""+course);
}
}
```

And here is my main class with main() method that needs the array:

```
public class SMSMain {
    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an instance of student object

    student a = new student();
    a.studentName = "Maria";
    a.studentID = 1236;
    System.out.println("Student Name:" + a.studentName);
    System.out.println("Student ID:" + a.studentID);
}
}
```

Comment: First declare and initialize an array of Student[] in the main method (note that the first letter of a class should be capitalized). Then fill it with Student instances. You should show us your attempt to do this so we can better understand just what you need help with.

Comment: Kindly remove all code from your post that is not *directly* relevant to the question (that would be most of your code btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initiate the array and create objects within loop.

```
   Student[] students;
    System.out.println("Enter number of students :");


    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    int n = in.readInt();
    students = new Student[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n ;i++) {
        students[i] = new Student();
        System.out.println("Name:");
        students[i].setName(in.readLine());
        System.out.println("Id:");
        students[i].setNewId(in.readInt());
     }
```

Comment: You should not post answers in Homework questions. Although we know the user didn't said it's homework, it's somewhat clear that he's learning, and instead of telling him the answer, we should help him to get to the answer with his own legs.

Comment: Thanks tsatiz, it is not home work, just book exercise i am doing because i am self learning java.